# Editing Connection String in ASP web.config include using ampersand

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, connection-string, configurationmanager

I have a configuration manager for setting up a web application before use. Included in this configuration manager is the setup for the connection string to the database. I have working code that will modify the connection string and save, but I have run into an issue that i cannot seem to correct.

The connection string contains an '&' character so when the string is saved to the web.config file, the string changes from "&" to "`&amp;`". I have tried a few different code variations to get past this, but nothing is working.

Here is the code to save the connection string:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");
ConnectionStringsSection section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings") as ConnectionStringsSection;

section.ConnectionStrings["DALEntities"].ConnectionString = string.Format("metadata=res://*/DALModel.csdl|res://*/DALModel.ssdl|res://*/DALModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source={0};initial catalog={3};persist security info=True;user id={1};password={2};multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;", settings.SQLserverName, settings.SQLuserName, settings.SQLpassword, settings.SQLdatabaseName);

config.Save();
```

This works to save the connection string, but this is what is saved to the web.config file:

```
<add name="DALEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DALModel.csdl|res://*/DALModel.ssdl|res://*/DALModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&amp;quot;data source=.\SQL2012;initial catalog=tooling_041718;persist security info=True;user id=mm;password=mm;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&amp;quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

As you can see, the `&amp;` was added to the connection string in two different spots.

I have tried escaping the '&' character by using `" + Regex.Escape("&") + "` instead of "&" in those two different spots in the string and I have tried taking out the `string.Format()` and have just a simple string.

Does anyone know if there is a way to escape the altering of the '&' when saving to the web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` before saving it, because when it saves, it encodes it using HTML encoding.

If you do this, it will convert the `&quot;` to `"`, and when saving, it will convert the `"` back to `&quot;`.

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");
ConnectionStringsSection section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings") as ConnectionStringsSection;

section.ConnectionStrings["DALEntities"].ConnectionString = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string.Format("metadata=res://*/DALModel.csdl|res://*/DALModel.ssdl|res://*/DALModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source={0};initial catalog={3};persist security info=True;user id={1};password={2};multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;", settings.SQLserverName, settings.SQLuserName, settings.SQLpassword, settings.SQLdatabaseName));

config.Save();
```

Or you could write the `"` (with escape: `\"`) instead of `&quot;` directly in your connection string:

```
section.ConnectionStrings["DALEntities"].ConnectionString = string.Format("metadata=res://*/DALModel.csdl|res://*/DALModel.ssdl|res://*/DALModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\"data source={0};initial catalog={3};persist security info=True;user id={1};password={2};multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework\"", settings.SQLserverName, settings.SQLuserName, settings.SQLpassword, settings.SQLdatabaseName);
```

Comment: Yep, this was it exactly. Thank you very much!

Comment: The first suggestion is the best for this answer. In that way, I can view what the string is supposed to look like before and after it is saved to the web.config. The "&quot;" should be visible before and after it is saved. Thank you.